# Spherical waves superposition

Tags: waves, interference

If two spherical waves are produced by two sources $S_1$ and $S_2$ as described in the picture [image]

From the superposition principle, we know that :
$$\Psi(M,t) = \Psi_1(M,t) + \Psi_2(M,t) = \frac{A_1}{r1}cos(\omega t - k r_1 + \phi_1) + \frac{A_2}{r2}cos(\omega t - k r_2 + \phi_2)$$

But how exactly does one derive the amplitude :

$$A(r_1,r_2) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{A_1}{r_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{A_2}{r_2}\right)^2 + 2\frac{A_1}{r_1}\frac{A_2}{r_2}cos[(kr_2-\phi_2)-(kr1-\phi_1)]}$$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me use the complex numbers to make our lives easier:

$$\Psi_1= \frac{A_1}{r_1} e^{i(\omega t - kr_1+\phi_1)}$$
$$\Psi_2= \frac{A_2}{r_2} e^{i(\omega t - kr_2+\phi_2)}$$

and thus the superposition of these waves is

$$\Psi_1+\Psi_2=  \frac{A_1}{r_1} e^{i(\omega t - kr_1+\phi_1)} + \frac{A_2}{r_2} e^{i(\omega t - kr_2+\phi_2)} $$

The square of the amplitude of a wave is given by its norm squared $\Vert \Psi_1+\Psi_2 \Vert^2$ hence

$$A(r_1,r_2)^2 = \left( \frac{A_1}{r_1} e^{i(\omega t - kr_1+\phi_1)} + \frac{A_2}{r_2} e^{i(\omega t - kr_2+\phi_2)}\right) \left( \frac{A_1}{r_1} e^{i(\omega t - kr_1+\phi_1)} + \frac{A_2}{r_2} e^{i(\omega t - kr_2+\phi_2)} \right)^* $$
$$=\left(\frac{A_1}{r_1} e^{i(\omega t - kr_1+\phi_1)} + \frac{A_2}{r_2} e^{i(\omega t - kr_2+\phi_2)} \right)
\left( \frac{A_1}{r_1} e^{-i(\omega t - kr_1+\phi_1)} + \frac{A_2}{r_2} e^{-i(\omega t - kr_2+\phi_2)} \right)$$
$$ = \left( \frac{A_1}{r_1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{A_2}{r_2} \right)^2 + \frac{A_1}{r_1}\frac{A_2}{r_2} \left( e^{i(kr_2-kr_1+\phi_1)} + e^{-i(kr_2-kr_1+\phi_2)} \right)$$

Notice that $z=a+ib \implies z+z^*= a+ib+a-ib= 2a = 2 \mathrm{Re}\{z\}$
$$\implies \Vert \Psi_1+\Psi_2 \Vert^2 = \left( \frac{A_1}{r_1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{A_2}{r_2} \right)^2 + 2 \frac{A_1}{r_1}\frac{A_2}{r_2} \mathrm{Re}\left\lbrace e^{i(kr_2-kr_1+\phi_1-\phi_2)} \right\rbrace $$

$$ = \left( \frac{A_1}{r_1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{A_2}{r_2} \right)^2 + 2 \frac{A_1}{r_1}\frac{A_2}{r_2}\cos(kr_2-kr_1+\phi_1-\phi_2) $$

Where I used $e^{i\alpha}=\cos(\alpha)+ i \sin(\alpha)$ in the last line. Thus the amplitude of a wave, which is given by $A(r_1,r_2)=\Vert\Psi_1+\Psi_2 \Vert$ is equal to
$$ A(r_1,r_2) = \sqrt{\Vert\Psi_1+\Psi_2 \Vert^2} =\sqrt{ \left( \frac{A_1}{r_1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{A_2}{r_2} \right)^2 + 2 \frac{A_1}{r_1}\frac{A_2}{r_2}\cos(kr_2-kr_1+\phi_1-\phi_2)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. When you say "The square of the amplitude of a wave is given by its norm squared $||\Psi_1+\Psi_2||^2$", where does that come from ?

Comment: It is basically the definition of the amplitude. Think of the complex function $\Psi$ as a vector in the complex plane having components $\begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}$ for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The amplitude is the length of this vector, which is easily calculated via Pythagorean Thm. If you have further questions regarding this or are still confused I can edit my answer to show this fact better.